# badge for marking n questions as 'exact duplicate' correctly

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge for migrating questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18255/badge-for-migrating-questions)
>   [Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions)

Seems like a good idea to me to have a badge for marking questions as exact duplicates in the close options correctly.  It's a good idea because it will provide motivation for people to actually close duplicates and not answer them, not to mention just reward users for good behavior.

Leaving the details up to designers, maybe closing as an exact duplicate *correctly* means that (1,2,3,4) other people who vote to close as a dupe choose the same question the original user did...

Comment: not quite sure its a duplicate, as this question is very specific on the action, and specifies *correctly* flagging as a duplicate, whereas the other question is about a badge for general closing of questions...

Comment: Sorry folks.  I've got migrations on the brain today.  You are right, and I repeal my suggestion of this being a duplicate.... (wish I could undo the vote)

Comment: Related [Reward finding duplicate questions - +10, +2, -5](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90620)

Comment: Woo, my first close vote on Meta, **where's my reward?** :)

Comment: yep, what a 'meta' experience.  For some reason I never search right :(

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems I can think of right now.

1. It can be abused. People can game the system and mark questions as duplicate of others that are not really duplicates just to get badges.
2. What if a closed question gets reopened?

Comment: if you are the first to mark a question as a dupe, and 2 or 3 others also mark the question as a dupe choosing the same dupe you did, i think its pretty strong confirmation.  The part about a question being reopened is a good catch, but does that really happen that often?  For questions that are dupes?